# 3D array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How to define ,dynamically initialize and print 3D array in vb.net ?

I have this code that return a 3d array and I have errors telling me the there is an argument out of range .. and when i seek the line i found nothing wrong ?

this is the function code :

```
Private Function readFESTWERTEBLOCK(ByVal FESTWERTEBLOCKString As String ) _
    As String (,,)

    Dim allX As System.Text.RegularExpressions .Group
    Dim allY As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group
    Dim allZ As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group
    Dim tempArray (,,) As String 
    Dim allXval As System.Text.RegularExpressions .MatchCollection
    Dim allYval As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection 
    Dim allZval As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection
    Dim oldUp ,midUp,newUp  As Integer 
    Dim a,b,c
    Dim myRegExpallX As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("WERT([\-\s\.0-9e]+)")
    Dim myRegExpallY As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("WERT([\-\s\.0-9e]+)")
    Dim myRegExpallZ As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("WERT([\-\s\.0-9e]+)")
    Dim myRegExpallXval As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[\w\-\.]+")
    Dim myRegExpallYval As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[\w\-\.]+")
    Dim myRegExpallZval As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[\w\-\.]+")

    ReDim tempArray (0 To 2 ,0 To -1, 0 To -1 )
    For a=0 To myRegExpallX.Matches(FESTWERTEBLOCKString).Count-1
        If myRegExpallX.Matches(FESTWERTEBLOCKString).Item(a).Groups.Count>1 And myRegExpallY.Matches(FESTWERTEBLOCKString).item(a).Groups.Count>1 AndAlso myRegExpallZ.Matches(FESTWERTEBLOCKString).item(a).Groups.Count>1 Then
            allX = myRegExpallX.Matches(FESTWERTEBLOCKString).Item(a).Groups.Item(1)
            allXval= myRegExpallXval.Matches(allX.Value.ToString())

            allY = myRegExpallY.Matches(FESTWERTEBLOCKString).Item(a).Groups.Item(1)
            allYval= myRegExpallYval.Matches(allY.Value.ToString())

            allZ = myRegExpallZ.Matches(FESTWERTEBLOCKString).Item(a).Groups.Item(1)
            allZval= myRegExpallZval.Matches(allZ.Value.ToString())

            oldUp= UBound(tempArray,3)
            midUp= UBound(tempArray , 3) + allXval.Count
            newUp=UBound(tempArray,3)+allXval.Count+allYval.Count

            ReDim Preserve tempArray(0 To 2 ,0 To midUp ,0 To newUp)
            For c=oldUp+2 To (allXval.Count+allYval.Count+oldUp)
                For b= midUp+2 To allXval.Count+midUp
                   Dim tmpMatchX As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match=allXval.Item(b-oldUp-2)
                   tempArray(0,b,c)=tmpMatchX.Value.ToString()
                   Dim tmpMatchY As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match=allYval.Item(b-oldUp-2)
                   tempArray(1,b,c)=tmpMatchY.Value.ToString()
                   Dim tmpMatchZ As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match=allZval.Item(b-oldUp-2)
                   tempArray(2,b,c)=tmpMatchZ.Value.ToString()
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Next       
    readFESTWERTEBLOCK = tempArray
End Function
```

Comment: You are mistaking this site for a "debug the code for me" help desk.  You are writing code from the previous century.  Rewrite it using List(Of T) so you don't need those awful Redim statements anymore.  Come back when you can't make *that* work.

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize a 3-dimensional array like this

```
Dim a(,,) As Double

a = New Double(5, 4, 10) {}
```

This array has the following index ranges

```
a(0..5, 0..4, 0..10)
```

And has a size of  6 x 5 x 11 elements.

---

If you have dimensions that can grow, use `List(Of T)` for them

```
Dim tempArray As List(Of List(Of String))() = New List(Of List(Of String))(2) {}

tempArray(0) = New List(Of List(Of String))()

tempArray(0).Add(New List(Of String)());
tempArray(0)(0).Add("Some string");
tempArray(0)(0).Add("Some other string");

tempArray(0).Add(New List(Of String)());
tempArray(0)(1).Add("XXX");
tempArray(0)(1).Add("YYY");
tempArray(0)(1).Add("ZZZ");

tempArray(0)(1)(2) ===> "YYY"
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply ; I am actually working in a pre made software so that is why i have lots of errors once i need to add a feature .. thank you i will come back if i cd not make it work